# Finding differences between words

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make my code have differentiate between eight words that start with different letters and all I can get is an if-else statement to work and I can't get an if-elif statement to work without having eight inputs popping up. I know this is a simle problem but I am new to python.

My code:

```
if input().lower().startswith('z'):
    print('yes')
elif input().lower().startswith('x'):
    print('no')
```

Comment: you could put your letters in a dict with required output as values to avoid 8 if/elifs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't call `input()` every time like that. Each call to `input()` will request more text from the user. Do it just once at the start and save it to some variable, and then compare that.

```
input_str = input().lower()
if input_str.startswith("z"):
  print "yes"
elif input_str.startswith("x"):
  print "no"
```

Comment: probably better using `input().lower()` no point repeatedly calling `.lower` on each check

Answer (score 4):

Store the input in a variable, then test that variable

```
text = input().lower()

if text.startswith("z"):
     # etc
```

Comment: `input` needs some `()`. I'd edit it myself, but not enough characters.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @Padraic_Cunningham's comment:

Rather than write out multiple `if` `elif` statements, you can create a dictionary storing the starting letter (the `key`) and the desire output (the `value`) for that letter.

```
letter_dict = {"a": "starts with an a",
               "h": "starts with an h",
                ...
               }

>>> word = input()
>>> Hello
>>> letter_dict[word[0].lower()]
>>> 'starts with an h'
```

Comment: +1 since I like this method ... but probably better doing `letter_dict.get(word[0].lower(),"starts with something else??")`